# How can I use WireGuard as a proxy?

Tags: networking, vpn, proxy, wireguard

I want to make my WireGuard client connect to the peer server behind a SOCKS5 proxy and only apply it to my browser, just like Tor Browser. But since WireGuard is a VPN implementation, it will create a virtual network connection, thus routing the whole system to the VPN.

Comment: Please [edit] this question to specify what operating system and browser you are considering and what implementation of wireguard you have in mind.

Comment: Maybe this could do what you want:
https://github.com/ambrop72/badvpn/wiki/Tun2socks#example-tunnelling-through-ssh

From my understanding it "socksifies" a TUN adapter e.g. a Wireguard virtual interface or similar..

Comment: https://github.com/kizzx2/docker-wireguard-socks-proxy

Answer (score 1):

You will need to place your browser inside something that provides it's own network stack thus controllable via networking rules. Usually this would be done by running your browser inside a virtual machine or container system (e.g. docker).

Android does this automatically by sand boxing *every app* inside it's own container and giving it a network stack. This allows system level IP routing to manage traffic from each app separately.

Some destkop app packaging systems are starting to do this as well, so you might be able to find a containerized browser that has it's own internal IP routing and could be manipulated to do this.

Otherwise your best bet is to setup a virtual machine (e.g. [Virtual Box](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=virtualbox&t=ffab&ia=web)) and separate your VPN apps from the system networking that way.